# calculation the similarity by using Jaccard Index Python

Tags: python, distance, similarity

I want to use Jaccard Index to find the similarity among elements of the dataframe (user_choices).

```
import scipy.spatial
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

user_choices = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
df_choices = pd.DataFrame(user_choices, columns=["User A", "User B", "User C", "User D", "User E", "User F"], 
                          index=(["User A", "User B", "User C", "User D", "User E", "User F"]))

df_choices
```

[image]

I wrote this code to calculate a Jaccard Index for my data:

```
jaccard = (1-scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(df_choices, df_choices,  
                                       metric='jaccard'))
user_distance = pd.DataFrame(jaccard, columns=df_choices.index.values,  
                             index=df_choices.index.values)

user_distance
```

But These are the outputs, which are identical to my data!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want `user_distance[i,j] = jaccard-distance(df_choices[i], df_choices[j])`

You can get this in two steps (1) calculate the pairs distance, this will get the distance for ordered pairs (2) obtain the square form from the condensed distance matrix.

```py
jaccard = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(df_choices, 'jaccard')
user_distances = pd.DataFrame(1-scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(jaccard), 
                              columns=df_choices.index.values,  
                              index=df_choices.index.values)
```

You have a symmetric matrix so the distance matrix is expected to be symmetric

For any pair of rows in your matrix there the elements are either all equal or all different, so the output matrix will have only ones and zeros.

if you try the same code with the following example

```py
user_choices = [[1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4], 
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

You will have output different from the input.

Comment: I agree with @jar, your matrix is correct. It is strange to me why you are computing the distance on a symmetric matrix, shouldn't the choices be computed in from a different domain?

Comment: I want to Calculate Jaccard similarity (measure of similarity ) not the Jaccard Jaccard index (measure of dissimilarity ) for each element, for example, user A and itself should be 1, etc.

Comment: Your input is constructed in a way that the Jaccard similarity of the output is the same equals the input, but the code computation itself is correct. Checkout the updated answer.

Comment: @ Bob and jar, thank you, i want to find a semantic similarity among these elements inorder to clustering the data based on their similarity

Answer (score 1):

- The Jaccard distance from eg user F with row vector (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1) to user A is zero; and you compute 1 - scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(...) = 1.
- The Jaccard distance from eg. user E with row vector (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0) to user A is one; you compute 1 - 1 = 0.

```py
>>> print(scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard(user_choices[0], user_choices[5]))
0.0
>>> print(scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard(user_choices[0], user_choices[4]))
1.0
```

You have perhaps accidentally arrived at some input that is identical to its own distance matrix when using Jaccard distance as a metric, minus one.

Maybe you don't want that (1-...) there?

Comment: I need it because I want to calculate Jaccard similarity (measure of similarity ) not the Jaccard Jaccard index (measure of dissimilarity ), for example for user A  and itself, the similarity should be 1, etc

Comment: If you define this similarity as `1 - Jaccard distance`, then given the values computed by  `scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard`, I would say the output is as expected.